# Output shape of numpy.einsum

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

Is there a elegant way to precompute the shape of the result from `np.einsum` given einsum's input arguments (without running the computation)?

```py
# Given a, b and signature with 
# a.shape == (1, 2, 5)
# b.shape == (4, 5)
einsum_shape('ijk,mk->ik', a, b) # returns (1, 5)
```

Comment: The shape is `ik`, where `i` is the first dimension of `a`, and `k` the last (of both `a` and `b`).

Comment: Yes, this is clear. I was looking for a function that einsum's output shape to preallocate array for einsum's result.

Comment: Why preallocate that array?  I believe the `out` parameter is of relatively recent origin.  For a one off call to `einsum` I don't think it buys you anything.  With repeated calls to the same `einsum` expression it might help, but then you could take the shape from the first of those.

Comment: @fhchl Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: @hpaulj In my code `einsum` is called tons of times and fills a larger, preallocated array. Preallocating that array, instead of concatenating the outputs of `einsum` feels more natural, even though I don't know if it is much faster. Maybe better in terms of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that works for generic number of inputs and relevant einsum-expression and also works for the specific scalar reduction case -

```
def einsum_outshape(einsum_expr, inputs):
    shps = np.concatenate([in_.shape for in_ in inputs])
    p = einsum_expr.split(',')
    s = p[:-1] + p[-1].split('->')
    if s[-1]=='':
        return ()
    else:
        inop = list(map(list,s))
        return tuple(shps[(np.concatenate(inop[:-1])[:,None]==inop[-1]).argmax(0)])
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: a = np.random.rand(1,2,5)
    ...: b = np.random.rand(4,5)
    ...: c = np.random.rand(5,7,8)
    ...: d = np.random.rand(7,9)

In [43]: einsum_outshape('ijk,mk,kpq,pr->ikpqr', inputs=(a,b,c,d))
Out[43]: (1, 5, 7, 8, 9)

# Reduction to a scalar
In [44]: einsum_outshape('ijk,mk,kpq,pr->', inputs=(a,b,c,d))
Out[44]: ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Divakar's answer, I came up with the following which is a bit more readable and raises errors, if unsupported subscript strings are passed.

```py
def einsum_outshape(subscripts, *operants):
    """Compute the shape of output from `numpy.einsum`.

    Does not support ellipses.

    """
    if "." in subscripts:
        raise ValueError(f'Ellipses are not supported: {subscripts}')

    insubs, outsubs = subscripts.replace(",", "").split("->")
    if outsubs == "":
        return ()
    insubs = np.array(list(insubs))
    innumber = np.concatenate([op.shape for op in operants])
    outshape = []
    for o in outsubs:
        indices, = np.where(insubs == o)
        try:
            outshape.append(innumber[indices].max())
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid subscripts: {subscripts}')
    return tuple(outshape)
```